# How HarpaAI extension is using my ChatGPT token?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, openai-api, browser-extension

So HarpaAI somehow is using my own ChatGPT session instead of using its own backend.
The question is how it is doing it?

Comment: It probably has the API server covered by its host_permissions or permissions in manifest.json. It may be also using `fetch` with `credentials: 'include'` parameter. It may be reading cookies directly via chrome.cookies API.